# How to input a float number using 'Input Text' from Selenium2Library

Tags: text, input, robotframework, floating, selenium2library

I have a field which requires me to input a float number on a free text field. I read the float number from excel.
However, I could not input the float number as I keep getting this error

> "TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()"

Let say I'm trying to put value **300.99** into a text box..

Do I need to convert into anything first?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet which throws this exception?

Comment: Please show the whole traceback if possible, and the part of your code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you need to modify the format of excel cell, where you wrote the value 300.99. By default, the cell is formatted to General format. If you need to read a float value from a cell then change the format to Text from General.

Now driver will read a text value (300.99) from that field and pass it as it is. You can change the format by right click on the excel cell (cell from where you are reading value)>>Format cells>>Click on Text>> Ok.

Please let me know if this is helpful

Thanks!!

Comment: It's very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for following one:

```
${var} =    Convert To String    ${var}
Log    ${var}
```

or

```
Log    ${var.__str__()}
```